# Will PWM on 50% duty cycle cut the current in a DC motor in half

Tags: pwm, dc-motor, current-measurement

I have a DC motor that is controlled by a PWM output on an Ardiono and I want to know if I can safely assume that by setting the output to 50% duty cycle, the current in the motor will be 50 % as well
The output is connected to the base on an BC338 transistor through a 1K resistor that I use as a driver.

Comment: Do you have a link to the DC motor controller, or even the motor itself, datasheet?

Comment: No... It is just something I removed from an old mobile I had. It is drawing 300 mA with 5 V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It can be anywhere from 0% to 100% depending on load & motor specifics.
If you need 50%, you need some feedback, like shunt with opamp.

//RPM counting using optical-interrupter

Comment: OP wants to control current, not RPM.  To control current, you need to take feedback from the current.

Comment: You right, fixed.

Comment: I´m using PWM to control the RPM actually. I just wanted to know if I could assume the current is halved if I use 50% cycle because there is some report writing involved and I didn´t want to look stupid when I presented it :)

Comment: Depending upon what the motor shaft is connected to, I would think a 50% PWM could cut motor current by more than 100%.  If the shaft is connected to something which wants it to turn at about 80% of its no-load full-voltage speed, and if the motor would take an amp if driven "full-on", 50% PWM could cause the motor to actually push about an amp back into the supply--a 200% "savings".

Answer (score 2):

Average current may well be half (not always), but instantaneous current could also be (not always) 100%.

I had some 3V motors I was PWMing from a 12V supply a couple of years back. PWM'ing them worked well in staying within the RPM range of those motors, but the instantaneous voltage/current wore out the brushes pretty quickly.